# Find and replace value in system.cfg php

Tags: php

I have a small script and with it I can go to `system.cfg`, find and replace value `32` to `33`. But what when I don't have value `32` and for example I have value `51` and I want to replace it with `33`? How to make `str_replace('code=< anyvalue >','code=33',$file_contents);`?

```
<?php
$file = 'system.cfg';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

$fh = fopen($file, "w");
$file_contents = str_replace('code=32','code=33',$file_contents);
fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Could be easier than replace, what does the file contents look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`. preg_replace allow you to find some string/number pattern an replace it with other string. But `str_replace` only replace the matched string not pattern.

```
 <?php
    $file = 'system.cfg';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

    $fh = fopen($file, "w");
    $file_contents = preg_replace('/code=(\d+)/', 'code=33', $file_contents);
    fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
    fclose($fh);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead.. You could find `code=` and capture in a group 1+ digits. Then in the replacement use code=32.

```
$re = '/code=(\d+)/';
$str = 'code=51';
$subst = 'code=32';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result; // code=32
```

You might also use a positive lookbehind `(?<=code=)\d+` or use  `code=\K\d+` which forgets what was used using `\K`.

Then in the replacement use `32` instead of code=32

If your match should not be part of a longer match, you might prepend and append a word boundary `\b` to the regex.